# Why am I getting "TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()" in this code?

Tags: python, json, typeerror

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@checks.serverowner()
async def change(self, ctx, change):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel('432738903221469186')
    change = ctx.message.clean_content[8:]
    now = datetime.now()
    count = len(self.changes.items()) + 1
    self.changes[count] = {'date': now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'change': change}
    dataIO.save_json('data/local/changes.json', self.changes)
    await self.bot.send_message(channel, bold("\N{SPARKLE} This change to the server was just made:") + box(change))
    await self.bot.add_reaction(ctx.message, "\N{WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK}")
```

Here is changes.json:

```
{
    "1" : {
        "change" : "TEST",
        "date" : "2018-06-29 01:07:37"
    }
}
```

Here's the full error:

```
2|cdb_laun | Traceback (most recent call last):
2|cdb_laun |   File "lib/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
2|cdb_laun |     ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
2|cdb_laun |   File "/root/craig/cdbot/cogs/local.py", line 73, in change
2|cdb_laun |     dataIO.save_json('data/local/changes.json', self.changes)
2|cdb_laun |   File "/root/craig/cdbot/cogs/utils/dataIO.py", line 20, in save_json
2|cdb_laun |     self._save_json(tmp_file, data)
2|cdb_laun |   File "/root/craig/cdbot/cogs/utils/dataIO.py", line 50, in _save_json
2|cdb_laun |     json.dump(data, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(",", " : "))
2|cdb_laun |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 178, in dump
2|cdb_laun |     for chunk in iterable:
2|cdb_laun |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 429, in _iterencode
2|cdb_laun |     yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
2|cdb_laun |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 352, in _iterencode_dict
2|cdb_laun |     items = sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
2|cdb_laun | TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

I apologize for the vague title and question, I've just dealt with handling JSON quite often and I'm not understanding the error here. I'm not even seeing where strings and integers are being compared.

My initial thought was that it had to do with `count = len(self.changes.items()) + 1` but it doesn't.

Comment: The line of _your_ code that triggers the error is `dataIO.save_json('data/local/changes.json', self.changes)`.  What is `self.changes`?

Comment: From the stack trace `dataIO.save_json('data/local/changes.json', self.changes)` is the problematic line from your code. What is the content of `self.changes`?

Comment: So the question is why is `json.dump()` calling `sorted()`. The only reason I can think of is because of `sort_keys=True`, and the keys of the dictionary contain a mix of strings and integers. This seems like a bug to me, it should probably convert the integers to strings before sorting, since JSON object keys are all strings.

Comment: It looks like you have a mixture of string & integer keys in your JSON dict, so the sorting breaks in Python 3.

Comment: Looks like this bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue25457

Comment: @Barmar Yes, `sort_keys=True` fails. I haven't tested it on very recent Python versions, I'd have thought this bug would have been fixed by now.

Comment: @PM2Ring See the discussion in the bug report.

Comment: @Barmar I've been aware of that bug report for a couple of years and discussed this bug with Aaron Hall before he made his posts there. I hadn't read it for a while, though, and had forgotten that the consensus was "won't fix". Another workaround is to do a json.dumps with `sort_keys=False` / json.load cycle to force all keys to strings, and then dump again with `sort_keys=True`, but of course that sorts the numbers lexicographically, not numerically, as mentioned in the bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I figured this out. For some reason, during the first run it saved the JSON key as a string. In the second run, it saved it as an integer. `self.changes` was printing as:

```
{'2': {'date': '2018-06-29 02:02:03', 'change': 'TEST'}, '1': {'date': '2018-06-29 01:07:37', 'change': 'TEST'}}
```

To fix that, I just changed

```
self.changes[count] = {'date': now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'change': change}
```

to

```
self.changes[str(count)] = {'date': now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'change': change}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue25457) in `json.dump()` when you use `sort_keys=True` and a dictionary has a mix of `int` and `string` keys.

You should either change `self.changes` so that it uses a consistent type for the dictionary keys. Or don't use the `sort_keys=True` option when calling `json.dump()` from `dataIO.save_json()` if you don't really need it.